# How to run a fake ASP.NET Core Web API for testing purpouses?

Tags: .net, testing, asp.net-web-api, mocking

I have two ASP.NET Core Web API projects, API-1 and API-2. API-1 is using the API-2 by sending requests internally via `new HttpClient().GetAsync("API-2 url")` I have a test project too. In that test project, I want to fake API-2 responses to do some tests on API-1. So, how can I run a fake (mock) version of API-2 in the test project?

Answer (score 1):

The [Moq Framework](https://github.com/moq/moq) is very useful for this. An approach that I use for cases like this is to abstract the calls to api-2 in a custom client that uses an underlying HttpClient. Basically something like this:

```cs
public class MyOwnHttpClient : IMyOwnHttpClient {

  readonly HttpClient _client;

  public MyOwnHttpClient() {
    _client = new HttpClient();
  }

  public async foo MyApiCall() {
    return await _client.GetAsync("API-2 url");
  }
}
```

```
public interface IMyOwnHttpClient  {
 
  foo MyApiCall();
}
```

You can then use [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq) in the test class to mock your own client interface and set it up to return whatever you want. It also has a ton of other useful features for unittesting.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass {

  private Mock<IMyOwnHttpClient> _client; // Our Api-2 Mock

  private Api1Class _api1Class; // Class that is using the client and is being tested here

  [TestMethod]
  public void Test() {
    _client.Setup(x => x.MyApiCall()).Returns(new foo);

    _api1Class = new Api1Class(_client.Object);
    _api1Class.MethodCall(); // Calling the method that uses the client

    _client.Verify(x => x.MyApiCall(), Times.Once);
  }
}
```

By the way, this should also work for your question from yesterday. You can just set it up to return a HtppResponse object with the error code you want.

Hope this helps. Let me know if anything is unclear.